# How to complete Merciless Punishement task from Inotia Ogre Mountains?

Tags: android, inotia-3

While playing **Inotia 3** version on Android, I've got stuck on the **Merciless Punishement** task. The ogre asks me to bring 10 crystals of darkness, when I got them, he is telling me that it's not enough and is giving me the same quest again and again.

I don't know if it is a bug, a forever-running quest, or it should be simply performed a given number of times (10 or 15 or whatever). So, is it possible to complete that quest, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found at [inotia3.gheroworld.com](http://inotia3.gheroworld.com):

> Unless you're around the ogre cave you can delete the Merciless Punishment quest. Judging by your level you're past that part already. It's a repeatable quest and most likely you've already completed it at least once so you'll lose nothing by deleting it.

So there'll be no problem If you just delete the quest, unless you want to go back to the cave surroundings to complete it again ;D

Ps. The forum is private, but here is there [google cache of the page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jWkJ3KKi7zcJ:inotia3.gheroworld.com/viewtopic.php%3Ff%3D14%26t%3D90#p1027) itself

Comment: But our Q&A is public :)

Answer (score 2):

The quest is repeatable, that's why it has (R) next to it.
Once you done it enough times (I only do it once), just dont talk to the quest giver. He'll have that exclimation mark for ever